# Ayuda con getter en android

Tags: android

Buen día a la comunidad. Soy novato en programación y necesito de su ayuda

Estoy trabajando con un sencillo ejemplo de android bajado de la web , indica si se conecta un audífono al teléfono a través de un mensaje rápido.
   Mi idea es aprovechar el valor de state de la clase MusicIntentReceiver y utilizarlo inicialmente para colocar un mensaje pero desde la clase principal.

La aplicación se instala en el teléfono correctamente y abre pero no muestra el mensaje "Hola pude sacar Valor". El archivo activity-main esta bien.

He estado investigando estos días en la web pero no lo he solucionado. La variable state se encuentra en private. private int state;

Que estoy haciendo mal ?. 
   Gracias.

```
//clase MusicIntentReceiver

    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG))
        {           
            state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);

            switch (state)

            {
                case 0:

                    Utilidades.mostrarToastText(context, "Headset is unplugged");
                  ;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Utilidades.mostrarToastText(context, "Headset is plugged");

                    break;
                default:
                    Utilidades.mostrarToastText(context, "I have no idea what the headset state is");


            }
        }
    } 





}
```

#### Clase principal

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


int state;


private MusicIntentReceiver myReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    myReceiver = new MusicIntentReceiver();


    state = myReceiver.getState();



    if (vibprueba==1) {

        txV= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textocentro);
        txV.setText("Hola pude sacar Valor");


   }

}
```

Comment: _Hasta ahora el getState no me ha funcionado_  ¿Qué es lo que no funciona, qué error da? Por favor, [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/104820/edit) colocando los mensajes de error.

Comment: creo que ignoraste algo en el código, si lo tienes tal cual como lo muestras, qué tipo de dato es `myReceiver `?

Comment: Gracias L.Ronquillo es private MusicIntentReceiver myReceiver;. Edite la pregunta y coloque el codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que te falta definir en el manifest, que tu clase se comportara como un broadcastRecievers y que debe filtrar la accion de conectar los audifonos. Te comparto el codigo.

```
<receiver android:name=".MusicIntentReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Adicional a eso, te comparto este código donde creo sacaste la parte que muestras has implementado. Presta especial atencion al método onResume() ya que debes registrarte al receiver y en onPause() eliminas la subscripcion, y este es el mejor lugar para hacerlo. Mucha suerte

```
package com.example.testmbr;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private MusicIntentReceiver myReceiver;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myReceiver = new MusicIntentReceiver();
}

@Override public void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    super.onResume();
}

private class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
            case 0:
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset is unplugged");
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.d(TAG, "Headset is plugged");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "I have no idea what the headset state is");
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override public void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo Jhon y efectivamente ese el código que tengo. Al agregarle las lineas al manifest la aplicación se instala y no abre. Y el logcat muestra la siguiente linea      java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG flg=0x40000010 (has extras) }

Comment: Comparte el logcat completo por favor.

Comment: Amigo Jhon, realicé un clean project y la aplicación corre. Voy a seguir investigando el método onResume ya que no realiza lo que deseo. Gracias por su atención y disculpe la novatada.

Comment: No te preocupes todos hemos pasado por eso jajaja, si te sirvió la respuesta por favor te agradezco el +1 y cuando lo soluciones no olvides cerrar la pregunta y comentarnos como lo arreglaste. Suerte

Comment: Amigo jhon todavía no tengo 15 punto de reputación para valorar. Igualmente estoy agradecido por su información y seguiré investigando hasta solucionar mi pequeña dificultad y colocar la solución.

Comment: Jhon pude comprobar los metodos onResume , onPause y también el onStart, y no es lo que deseo. Realmente amigo  entiendo el algoritmo de lo que estoy haciendo pero estoy aprendiendo android . Yo programo microcontroladores Pic y trabajo un poco con eso. MI objetivo es realizar una aplicación android para la personas con tartamudez, tengo el prototipo en físico y quiero realizar la app. Soy un aficionado a la programación y voy muy lento. En general lo que deseo es activar un Button, si  conecto el auricular , si no el Button se mantenga visible pero inactivo.

Comment: Investigue que se puede utilizar  setEnabled(false). Por eso es que inicialmente necesito conocer valores de algunas variables para seguir construyendo el algoritmo, pero con el método getter no he obtenido el valor.  Si me pudiese decir como orientarme o que investigar le estaría agradecido.

Comment: El programa corre sin problemas pero no obtengo el valor de state de la clase MusicIntentReceiver en la clase principal.

Comment: Ayer Implemente los métodos que usted me indicó pero presentó un detalle. Al utilizar el método onResume o onStart si desconecto el auricular el botón siguen activo hasta que ponga la aplicación en segundo plano y luego la vuelva a lanzar. Es decir la respuesta no es inmediata. Que podría hacer para corregir eso ?.