# Enviar entero de una clase a un Mainactivity

Tags: android-studio

Buenas Tardes a la comunidad. Necesito de su ayuda para resolver un problema de novato como yo, pero que me tiene atascado.

En general lo que deseo es enviar un dato entero desde una segunda clase extendida en BroacastReceiver a la clase principal Mainactivity.

El programa que estoy utilizando es el siguiente [programa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104820/ayuda-con-getter-en-android)

Disculpen mi franqueza. Realmente no pido que  solucionen el problema sin yo hacer nada pero si podrían ser un poco sencillo en su expresión lo agradecería. Soy un novato en esto de programación ,pero esta etapa es solo una parte del proyecto.

Esperando una respuesta le agradezco por su tiempo.

Comment: A ver si entiendo. Quieres obtener el valor de un BroadcastReceiver en el activity?

Comment: El programa que estoy utilizando lo puedes ver en el enlace y es bajado de internet. La función es indicar mediante un mensaje rápido si se conecto o no un auricular de cable.El programa funciona y corre en el teléfono perfecto. Ahora La idea que tengo es utilizar una variable entera o boolean que me indique en la clase MainActivity cuando se conecta o desconesta el mismo para activar o desactivar un botón y reproducir un sonido especifico. Esa es mi idea ,quizás no es muy buena. Espero su sugerencia. Los métodos onResume, onPause u onStart no cumplen lo que yo quiero.

Comment: Y ese dato lo deseo tomar de la clase que extendida a BroadcastReceiver y enviarla a Mainactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Si editamos la respueta de la pregunta [Ayuda con getter en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104820) que hiciste. Solo tendriamos que implementar el metodo `onReceive` en `onCreate` y luego activar/desactivar el button segun el estado:

```
//..
private MusicIntentReceiver myReceiver;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Buttton)findViewById(R.id.id_boton);

    myReceiver = new MusicIntentReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
            case 0:
            // desactivamos el buton
               button.setEnabled(false);
                break;
            case 1:
            // activamos
               button.setEnabled(true);
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "I have no idea what the headset state is");
            }
        }
   };
}

@Override public void onResume() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Implemente los métodos que usted me indica ahora y que  me sugirió el amigo Jhon pero presentó un detalle. Al utilizar el método onResume o onStart  si desconecto el auricular el botón siguen activo hasta que ponga la aplicación en segundo plano y luego la vuelva a lanzar. Es decir la respuesta no es inmediata. Que podría hacer para corregir eso ?.

Comment: Ese tema es desconocido para mi. Tendras que darme tiempo para investigar.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias le agradezco su respuesta...Me podría ayudar con lo siguiente ¿ Es factible enviar un dato de la clase MusicIntentReceiver a MainActivity, cuales son los metodos que se utilizan,donde puedo ver un ejemplo sencillo ?